# iOS App Default Language

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app that support both Chinese and English, and when my phone is configured to Chinese or English, things display quite normally, but when my phone is in French(by default the interface would be in English), everything is in English EXCEPT the UIActivityViewController is in Chinese that will pop up once user click a "share" button in my app.

I do not know how to modify this, any helps will be appreciated.

Note: my app uses a Localize-Swift library which allows user to choose a desired language from the settings within the app which means the app language could be different from the system language, if user chooses one from the app then switch to another system lang. Also, English IS set to be the development language in Xcode and Base Localization is NOT used.

Comment: perhaps the Storyboard is not localized?

Comment: mention code for how to change language ?

Comment: @finalstatic The storyboard is localized with Chinese and English but not Base

Comment: @KKRocks There is a library called Localize-Swift on GitHub https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift